# how to excluded directory from nginx conf?

Tags: regex, nginx

in nginx conf file,i use:

```
location ~ \.jsp {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:86;
}
```

to parse my jsp file, now,i want excluded directory `/upload/`

this directory is user upload file directory ,don't need parse JSP file.(`http://example.com/upload/`)

how to change my `location ~ \.jsp {` ?

i need parse JSP `*.jsp` but excluded `/upload/` and it's subdirectory.

thanks all :)

Comment: Your upload directory should (ideally) be outside the webroot completely, which would remove this particular problem. (Though of course the question of how to exclude a directory may still be valid.)

Comment: thank you,you are right, but i still want to know my question answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a list of Nginx Core Directives:
http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule

By skimming through these I can see there's probably more than one way to achieve this. I can't test it, but here's something that may work:

```
error_page 403 /forbidden.html;
location ^~ /upload/ {
    deny all;
}
```

**However**, I would advise against this; your upload directory should *never* sit inside your web root. You should simply move the folder to achieve what you're asking.